# WebStorm, Gulp can't import bourbon

Tags: node.js, sass, gulp, webstorm, bourbon

I have the following `gulpfile.js` in my WebStorm 2016 IDE. My SCSS stylesheets currently reside in `src/scss/style.scss` where I do all my @import's.

After doing ton of research and spending hours trying to figure this out, I am not able to do `@import "bourbon";` in my main scss file. I am guessing that something is not correct in the gulp file, second my IDE shows a redline on any npm package imports I do (meaning it is not able to see the correct path to the node_modules).

Has anyone been able to figure out how to configure this? Any help is appreciated it, thank you.

**gulfile.js**

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
        uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
        jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
        header  = require('gulp-header'),
        rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
        package = require('./package.json');

    var paths = {
      scss: './src/scss/*.scss'
    };

    var sass_config = {  // THE INCLUDES FOR BOTH PROD AND DEV
      includePaths: [
        require('node-neat').includePaths
      ],
      style: 'compressed',
      quiet: true,
      sourcemap: true
    };

    var banner = [
      '/*!\n' +
      ' * <%= package.name %>\n' +
      ' * <%= package.title %>\n' +
      ' * <%= package.url %>\n' +
      ' * @author <%= package.author %>\n' +
      ' * @version <%= package.version %>\n' +
      ' * Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + '. <%= package.license %> licensed.\n' +
      ' */',
      '\n'
    ].join('');

    gulp.task('css', function () {
        return gulp.src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass(sass_config).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 4 version'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
    });

    gulp.task('js',function(){
      gulp.src('src/js/scripts.js')
        .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
        .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true, once: true}));
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
        browserSync.init(null, {
            server: {
                baseDir: "app"
            }
        });
    });
    gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
        browserSync.reload();
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
        gulp.watch("src/scss/*/*.scss", ['css']);
        gulp.watch("src/js/*.js", ['js']);
        gulp.watch("app/*.html", ['bs-reload']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code tweak got my Bourbon and Neat to start working via imports in my SCSS files. However, I still have an issue with WebStorm giving me a red underscore under @import "bourbon" with error "cannot resolve file bourbon" in the IDE. However, it is working so I am thinking somehow it is not able to resolve the proper path. If anyone knows a solution to that please comment.

```
        var gulp = require('gulp'),
            sass = require('gulp-sass'),
            browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
            autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
            uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
            jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
            header  = require('gulp-header'),
            rename = require('gulp-rename'),
            cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
            package = require('./package.json');

        var paths = {
          scss: 'src/scss/*.scss'
        };

        var sass_config = {  // THE INCLUDES FOR BOTH PROD AND DEV
          includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths,
          style: 'compressed',
          quiet: true,
          sourcemap: true
        };

        var banner = [
          '/*!\n' +
          ' * <%= package.name %>\n' +
          ' * <%= package.title %>\n' +
          ' * <%= package.url %>\n' +
          ' * @author <%= package.author %>\n' +
          ' * @version <%= package.version %>\n' +
          ' * Copyright ' + new Date().getFullYear() + '. <%= package.license %> licensed.\n' +
          ' */',
          '\n'
        ].join('');

        gulp.task('css', function () {
            return gulp.src(paths.scss)
            .pipe(sass(sass_config).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 4 version'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
            .pipe(cssnano())
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
        });

        gulp.task('js',function(){
          gulp.src('src/js/scripts.js')
            .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
            .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
            .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
            .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
            .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true, once: true}));
        });

        gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
            browserSync.init(null, {
                server: {
                    baseDir: "app"
                }
            });
        });
        gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
            browserSync.reload();
        });

        gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
            gulp.watch("src/scss/**/*.scss", ['css']);
            gulp.watch("src/js/*.js", ['js']);
            gulp.watch("app/*.html", ['bs-reload']);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require('node-neat').includePaths` is an array itself, and `includePaths` option in your `sass_config` variable should be an array itself, not an array of arrays. So the possible solution, as you have already mentioned, is to just pass `require('node-neat').includePaths` to `includePaths` option as it is without square brackets, like so:

```
var sass_config = {
    includePaths: require('node-neat').includePaths,
    ...
};
```

For passing multiple arrays of this kind you can also try concatenating them like so:

```
var sass_config = {
    includePaths: [].concat(
        require('node-neat').includePaths,
        require('bourbon').includePaths
    ),
    ...
};
```

As for an error in WebStorm/PhpStorm when importing the library, check the [answer by @Shawn Lovelidge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40024331/12320578).

Basically, you have to follow these steps:

1. Go to `File` Menu > `Settings` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Click `Directories` on the left menu
3. Right click on your `node_modules` directory and check `Resource Root` option
   (or left click on the folder and press `Resource Root` button at the top).